# Develop a project with two names?

Tags: java, git, project-management

I'm developing an open-source project that is both for a company under one name, and for the community under another name. I would like to be able to easily pass the changes from one to another, but the name and the license are different, so I don't know how to just apply the modifications from one to the other. Let's give an example:

```
ProjectOne :
file : src/main/projectone.main :
-> /** This file is part of ProjectOne... **/
-> contentA

ProjectTwo :
file : src/main/projecttwo.main :
-> /** This file is part of ProjectTwo... **/
-> contentA
```

Now, consider that I'm modifying the content of projectTwo :

```
contentA -> contentB
```

I get :

```
ProjectOne :
file : src/main/projectone.main :
-> /** This file is part of ProjectOne... **/
-> contentA

ProjectTwo :
file : src/main/projecttwo.main :
-> /** This file is part of ProjectTwo... **/
-> contentB
```

I would like to be able to easily modify ProjectOne as well, but keeping its own license, package and project name...

```
ProjectOne :
file : src/main/projectone.main :
-> /** This file is part of ProjectOne... **/
-> contentB

ProjectTwo :
file : src/main/projecttwo.main :
-> /** This file is part of ProjectTwo... **/
-> contentB
```

My project uses Maven for dependencies, Netbeans as IDE and git to manage revisions. Is there a trick (branch, plugin...) that could help me do that?

Comment: Why not fork the projects to have two versions?

Comment: Ok, seems a good start. So I fork the project. Then I change every "ProjectOne" into "ProjectTwo" in all files of my fork. Then, I want every other modifications be repercuted from one project to another, except the initial change of names. How can I do that ?

Comment: If you fork, you will end merging new features to both. And then a new feature changes those files, then will be propagated. A suggestion is to work only on one project, and script what should be copied (its a copy/paste operation at the end, right?), since you dont code on ProjectB. Does it make sense?

Comment: Hum maybe you're right. At least, it will do the thing as long as there are no other difference in the 2 versions. Thanks for helping me think through it. Edit : someone suggested me to use one project as a dependence of the other. Maybe I should think about it ?

Comment: cherry-picking could do the trick but you might want to rely on patching functionality more than that...

Comment: Yes, I know... But I don't see how

Comment: Put the common stuff in common shared files, and put the project specific stuff in project specific files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put the name and the license in a separate file, use only one trunk and release the two versions using the right name/license file. I suggest to automate the release making process using a script which takes the correct name/license file and the final build and produce the custom release.

Comment: would be nice if it were so easy. from what I take of the question it seems that the license is included into a javadoc header to the files...

Comment: Yes, exactly. The license is in each file and the name of the project appears in the package name...

Comment: license text can be easily added with some scripting code (grep+cat+sed)... are you developing under linux? Have a look at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139926/shell-script-bash-to-add-or-replace-the-license-text-contained-within-c-h. If your are developing under windows you're screwed, pray for VisualStudio/Eclipse to have such editing feature! :-)

Comment: I'm under Linux fortunately ^^. I think you're right. I can have my project with 2 branches, and just a script to convert the files to make them fit the other project, replacing names, licence, etc, from each file. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

make project-name directory in the content directory (folder)

**Example :** you have two project named :

```
       1. Proj1 
       2. Proj2
```

and you have content directory named content in which your storing license files. Now what you have to do is that make two directory in content directory i.e.

```
       content / proj1 / license.htm
               / proj2 / license.htm
```

in the same way whatever you want to differentiate in project make their directory with same name i.e. proj1 and proj2. You may required to do this in images logo, background and many other things as per project. Make one properties file in that you put a field in which you have to specify any one name of project or build i.e. proj1 or proj2 and dynamically you have to decide which you to use.

And this way your static content will be different but your logic and code will be same.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you mean. If I do this I will have the same content all the time in the 2 projects except the project name, isn't it ?

Comment: no no i have edit my ans to give you brief description.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Indeed it is a good idea for differentiate files, but I also need to change the content of the source files (javadoc header)...

Comment: that also (i mean change content) you can do easily. we are managing projects in this way and this helps us in many ways. So i just said. its fine whichEver way you consider but this is also one of the way you can consider. Thats it. Thanks

Comment: Ok. Anyway, I will keep this in mind. Maybe if my script reaches its limits I will use your approach. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

You may also try developing a script that replaces any references to the project name in the source code/filenames.